Auto update to files with in PWA and SharePoint
I am a new PWA user. I have my projects stored in SharePoint and I load them to PWA. My team makes their updates to the files in SP. Is there a way for automatically updating files in PWA when user makes their updates to the files in SharePoint.
Or
How do I get the Project manager make update to tasks/ projects in PWA when he/she is not assigned to projects/tasks
